# libnlopt.so.0 cannot open shared object file

Tags: package-management

What does this error mean?

```
ImportError: libnlopt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to run python2 [script](https://github.com/chrysante87/pyterpol/wiki/Installation) that required nlopt.

nlopt was installed by

```
pip2 install --user nlopt
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting nlopt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/4f/de7e64a295e86c9f1ee382076019e0526247969353eb29345da1a05854b6/nlopt-2.4.2.post2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from nlopt) (1.13.3)
Installing collected packages: nlopt
  Running setup.py install for nlopt ... done
Successfully installed nlopt-2.4.2.post2
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that a shared library could not be loaded. You might solve the problem by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install libnlopt0
```

And then run your command.

That is, if you are running Debian/Ubuntu or derivatives. If not, use whatever command your distribution uses to add a package, in this case `libnlopt0`.

Comment: Thank you very much